How to fix kernel drivers on Virtualbox?
I'm using Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, and I have an issue with VirtualBox. everytime I try booting a virtual machine, I get this error:
"Kernel driver not installed (rc=1908)
The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please try setting it up again by executing
/sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
You may have EFI Secure Boot enabled, please disable it."
Ok, I have secure boot off and I have tried  to execute the command "/sbin/vboxconfig" without root and "sudo /sbin/vboxconfig" with root. Neither worked.
PLease help.

look and add the errors from /var/log/vbox-setup.log It will show errors, Likely missing gcc or a wrong version or a compiler issue

sudo apt install virtualbox-dkms ?

This question is similar to: Virtualbox Kernel driver not installed. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
